# Does getting shares when mining mean that I have earned a reward?

Tags: mining-pools, mining-reward, miner-configuration, mining-pool-shares

So I have 13 Total Shares (Non Rejected) and my pool is Mining Pool Hub. It does not show that I have gained any Ethereum when I go to Dashboard (Under Ethereum) on Mining Pool Hub. Do accepted shares mean that I earned coin or no?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you are asking about Ethereum instead of Bitcoin.  Assuming mining works the same for both is okay, and if you explained that, then you could admit that getting the answer for Bitcoin might be helpful.  As you asked it, any answer for Bitcoin wouldn't be helpful, so this is off-topic.

Answer (score -1):

You probably have gained no Ethereum as of yet because even if your shares were accepted by the pool it doesn't mean they were accepted by the network. When your pool mines it's next block the percentage of your shares of the total network will be the percentage of the block reward you get.